# Swiper v10 Effects, Navigation nd Center Slides Not Working Properly

Tags: swiper.js

Actually, I don't know how to describe it, but it seems nothing works with Swiper v10, Effect, Centered Slide, Navigation buttons working for the first time only and stopped working without a console error.

**P.S. Pagination Working fine**

I saw this very simple example which is exactly what I need, I thought I made something wrong on my own local, But after I changed resources in the example itself to the new v10 [css and js], it corrupted as well.

```
https://codepen.io/tbego/pen/LrozoY

<div class="bk-slider">
  <div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #51cce2, #3369e7);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

.bk-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0 100px;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f69259, #f16975);
  transform: scale(1.4);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* ARROWS */
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  color: #f69259;
}

/* PAGINATION */
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f69259, #f16975);
}
```

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
    },
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

I have [.swiper, .swiper-wrapper, .swiper-slide] classes and the effect set on [slide] but it [show/hide] without any animation.

I removed all my custom styles, but nothing helped.

Comment: Your Q is too general (What is the problem exactly). If you change versions you should follow the docs Migration Guides.